# Yii Как организовать выбор типа вывода?

Tags: yii

К примеру, для товара нужен фильтр либо он из Китая либо из других стран. Есть кнопка изменения фильтра, которая видна пользователю всегда. Если он выбрал китай, надо чтоб ему пожизненно выводился китайский товар, если он не изменит на другие страны.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cookie или атрибуты пользователя, если он авторизован. Лучше куки.

Comment: я тут подумала, а может это реально организовать, если в CApplication завести поле хранящее выбор и изменять его?

Comment: а как вы собираетесь долговременно хранить зачение переменной в CApplication????

Comment: Если авторизирован пользователь, хранить в атрибутах оптимальный вариант